# Did SoundCloud API just change without notice?

Tags: ios, soundcloud

I have an app using SoundCloud's search service (tracks.json). It used to work fine but now all of a sudden it's crashing for some of our users.

This is the call I'm making:

https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks.json?consumer_key=[YOUR_KEY]&q=music&filter=streamable&order=default&limit=50

I'm either getting an array returned, or a dictionary with the array inside a "collection" key. The result is inconsistent. I first assumed they were in the middle of a deployment but it's been like this for about 12 hours and still the same. I've also further discovered the following:

1. West coast users are getting the dictionary
2. West coast users making the same call over http (not https) get an array
3. East coast users are getting an array over https (unsure of http)

I noticed this blog post by their devs:
https://developers.soundcloud.com/blog/offset-pagination-deprecated
However that post doesn't mention anything about the response format changing. It also looks like that changed should have happened 2 months ago.

Is this just a bug on their part? Are they in the middle of a deployment? Anyone else seeing this? Is the response expected to be a dictionary now?

**UPDATE:**

This problem seems to be explicitly tied to searching for that URL. If I move the parameters around the response changes. This isn't a local caching issue since I confirmed the problem from someone else as well. My best guess is SoundCloud rolled something back but this URL is cached either by our ISP or SC itself.

Comment: Would't it be better to post this question on the SoundCloud support page?

Comment: Yes except they say to post it here :-) https://developers.soundcloud.com/support

Comment: I'm getting exactly the same - from two similar queries, it randomly returns differently as specified in the question. This issue has broken my production application.

Comment: https://developers.soundcloud.com/blog/offset-pagination-deprecated

Answer (score 2):

It looks like SoundCloud just messed up because now I'm seeing the change rolled back. It took a while for the cache to clear though and reach all our users. This isn't the first time SC changed their API schema on us with little to zero notice. I have very little confidence that this won't happen again so I'll be wrapping their service inside a dummy one that we can fix behind the scenes without an app update.

Very disappointing that they've remained completely silent on this issue. I see no mention of any API changes, bad-deployments, etc on their twitter feed: https://twitter.com/SoundCloudDev

Comment: Still having a massive issue with some of my apps requests being cached and returning wrong? Any workarounds?

Comment: We're still getting some reports from users that it's crashing but for majority of them it's working again now.

Comment: Thanks Oren, not sure whether it's worth re-writing some stuff to handle this or just wait?

Comment: I rewrote the code and had it ready to escalate with apple before I realized that it may be a bug on their end vs a known change. So i rolled back my change. I would wait it out but as I suggest above, probably best to wrap their API so that you won't need an app update if this happens again. This is the 2nd time we've been burned by their API in only a few months.

Comment: Yup wrote a wrapper and deployed to avoid this happening again, just need our queries to start working and we will be as good as new. :)

Comment: If you're making the SC call server side, try switching the parameters around now so the URL is different but functionally the same. That will bypass the cache and worked for me.

Comment: and now I'm seeing the Dictionary being returned again! They reverted the response yet again!!!

Comment: so it's broken again? ... jesus.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove .json from the request. Seem to work for me.